# How to create a table that adds a row for every sheet created?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm trying to help my dad (more or less 0 understanding of every aspect of IT) to check his expenses.
So far I created everything he needs, based on facts that every year he has to create a new sheet to track his data (E.G. "22/23","23/24","24/25"...) when he needs to.
What i find hard to achieve is , assuming i have a sheet called "total" which has to gather data from every sheet and do some calculations, find a way to create a table which has a "trigger" that adds a row everytime he adds a new sheet and gather data from it.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT: is difficult to post an example sheet because what i'm trying to achieve is all dynamic.
I try to better phrase the scenario.

I Have 2 sheets, "Calculations" and "22/23".
Let's say 22/23.A1 has the value "test"

In Calculations A1 i'd want to have "22/23" and in A2 "test"

BUT

if my father adds a new sheet called "23/24" with A1:"Test1"

i'd also want :

```
    A      B
1  22/23   test
2  23/24   test1
```

And so on

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `assuming i have a sheet called "total" which has to gather data from every sheet and do some calculations, find a way to create a table which has a "trigger" that adds a row everytime he adds a new sheet and gather data from it.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried to better phrase the scenario

Comment: You will find people faster in suggesting solutions to you if you share with them a spreadheet with dummy data illutrating very well your situation, what you have tried and you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Would you be fine with using Google Apps Script to accomplish what you'd like to do? I believe Google Sheet Formulas might not be suitable for what you explained.

Comment: @Saddles i searched online and probably is the only way to go , did'nt know it was possible but i'll learn it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### RECOMMENDED SOLUTION

Try using the [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that Google Apps Script offers to automate what you'd like to do.

To access the script editor from the Google Sheet, click on **Extensions** > **Apps Script** from the toolbar.

[image]

To add the installable trigger, click on **Triggers** > **+ Add Trigger** on the left of the Google Apps Script.

[image]

You may use this sample script as a reference for what you'd like to accomplish:

> I have also added some explanations of what the code does

```
const myFunction = () => {
  // Gets your current active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Gets all the sheets in the spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // Gets the sheet named "Calculations"
  var calculationsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculations");
  // Initialization of a new array
  var checkAllSheets = new Array();
  // Goes through all the sheets. Gets their name as well as the value of their "A1" cells
  for (let i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    checkAllSheets.push([sheets[i].getName(), sheets[i].getRange('A1').getValue()]);
  }
  // Gets the range of the "Calculations" sheet and pastes the values gathered on it's "A1" cell
  calculationsSheet.getRange(1, 1, checkAllSheets.length, checkAllSheets[0].length).setValues(checkAllSheets);
}
```

I recommend running the code at least once, just so that the authorizations will be allowed.

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)
- [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Comment: I tried it in a personal sheets and the solution helped me a lot (basically opened me a whole world, thank you ) but in the specific scenario I am an editor and not the owner of the file and I can't add extensions.
Is there a role-limitation?

Comment: I'm glad that helped you out! As for `I am an editor and not the owner of the file and I can't add extensions. Is there a role-limitation?` No, I replicated it to be sure. As an editor, you should be able to access Google Apps Script. Can you try accessing the file using an incognito tab or another browser to see if anything happens? If that doesn't work, I can recommend that you remove your access to the file and put it back in by asking your dad or by doing it yourself on their computer. If that doesn't work as well, are you using a personal Gmail account or Google Workspace?